# Storing input in a dictionary to add to a master list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program that asks the user for a first and a last name, then stores that name and asks for another. I can write code to ask for the names and can get the program to display the names. The problem is the names aren't saving. Do I need to make a list to save the names?

I have tried tweaking the program multiple times but with no luck.

```
def make_names(first_name, last_name):

    first_name = first_name.strip()
    last_name = last_name.strip()


    full_block = {'First name: ': first_name, 'Last Name': last_name}
    return full_block

while True:

    first_name = input("Enter the first name of someone you know, press q to exit: ")
    last_name = input("Enter the last name of someone you know, press q to exit: ")

    if first_name == 'q' or last_name == 'q':
        print("You pressed q, quitting..")
        break

    else:
        full_name = make_names(first_name, last_name)
        print(full_name)
```

The expected result to would to store all names entered then display them in the end.

Comment: You never store `full_name` anywhere. You return the `dict` then print it but you don't store it...

Comment: It's better to use OOP for this. Write a class containing 2 methods. To enter names, to show names. Have an instance variable named **names** to store the entered names.

Comment: @thefence2113 Just have a look at my answer now. Please comment you are stuck. Your approach is right if you are using functional approach. I have provided an OOP solution. You will like it. Because finally you will move to that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your result in a list such as:

```
def make_names(first_name, last_name):

    first_name = first_name.strip()
    last_name = last_name.strip()


    full_block = {'First name: ': first_name, 'Last Name': last_name}
    return full_block

full_list = []
while True:

    first_name = input("Enter the first name of someone you know, press q to exit: ")
    last_name = input("Enter the last name of someone you know, press q to exit: ")

    if first_name == 'q' or last_name == 'q':
        print("You pressed q, quitting..")
        break

    else:
        full_name = make_names(first_name, last_name)
        print(full_name)
        full_list.append(full_name)
print(full_list)
```

That being said I wouldn't use a `dict` for this. Instead use something like a `namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Person = namedtuple("Person", "first_name last_name")

def make_names(first_name, last_name):

    first_name = first_name.strip()
    last_name = last_name.strip()


    return Person(first_name, last_name)
persons = []
while True:

    first_name = input("Enter the first name of someone you know, press q to exit: ")
    last_name = input("Enter the last name of someone you know, press q to exit: ")

    if first_name == 'q' or last_name == 'q':
        print("You pressed q, quitting..")
        break

    else:
        full_name = make_names(first_name, last_name)
        print(full_name)
        persons.append(full_name)
for person in persons:
    print("First Name: {} --- Last Name: {}".format(person.first_name, person.last_name))
```

Comment: Using a namedtuple helped a ton. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just create an empty list before start your loop, then add each full_name dictionary to the list.

```
names = []
while True:

    first_name = input("Enter the first name of someone you know, press q to exit: ")
    last_name = input("Enter the last name of someone you know, press q to exit: ")

    if first_name == 'q' or last_name == 'q':
        print("You pressed q, quitting..")
        break

    else:
        full_name = make_names(first_name, last_name)
        names.append(full_name)
        print(full_name)

print(names)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I had mentioned in my comment, the **OOP** approach will be best for this. I just copied few lines of your code and implemented using **OOP**.

> **Note1:** Few lines are documented with comments so do not forget to read.
>
> I have also given o/p of my terminal. Here I have just entered first & last names of 2 people, stored them in a list as dictionaries.
>
> `make_names()` method asks user to input first & last names until he/she presses `q`.
>
> `show_all_names()` method returns a list of dictionaries.
>
> `show_name()` method returns a single dictionary object (n denotes the place of item in list).
>
> **Note2:** Just copy the code, paste in a file (in my case `name.py`) and run from terminal (In my case, `python3 name.py`).

```
class Name(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.names = []

    def make_names(self):
        while True:
            names = {} # Dictionary to store `first_name` & `last_name`

            first_name = input("Enter the first name of someone you know, press q to exit: ")
            if first_name == "q":
                break
            else:
                names["first_name"] = first_name

            last_name = input("Enter the last name of someone you know, press q to exit : ")
            if last_name == "q":
                # If no `last_name`, remove `first_name` (you can write your own logic as you want) 
                del names['first_name']
                break
            else:
                names["last_name"] = last_name
                self.names.append(names)

    def get_all_names(self):
        return self.names

    def get_name(self, n):
        # `n` will be 1 if you want to get the first entered names in the list & so on
        try:
            name = self.names[n-1]
        except Exception as err:
            name = None
            print(err) # list index out of range

        return name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    name = Name()
    name.make_names()

    name_list = name.get_all_names()

    import json
    print(json.dumps(name_list, indent=4)) # PRETTY PRINT 
    # [
    #     {
    #         "first_name": "Rishikesh",
    #         "last_name": "Agrawani"
    #     },
    #     {
    #         "first_name": "Hemkesh",
    #         "last_name": "Agrawani"
    #     }
    # ]

    name1 = name.get_name(1)
    print(name1)
    # {'first_name': 'Rishikesh', 'last_name': 'Agrawani'}

    name2 = name.get_name(2)
    print(name2)
    # {'first_name': 'Hemkesh', 'last_name': 'Agrawani'}

    name3 = name.get_name(3) # None (only 2 names are there in this case)
    print(name3)
    # None
```

> Output (Picture of my terminal)

[image]

Thank you very much.